# Spring Tool Suit- Issue with launching Spring Starter Project

Tags: spring-tool-suite

While launching Spring Starter Project , I am getting below exception. STS version 3.7.0  . I am new to Spring , any help is appreciated.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.fx.core 4 0 2015-07-22 11:09:51.697
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.fx.core [412]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="2.0.100.v20150311-1658"
       org.eclipse.jdt.annotation [421]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

```
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely ignore that error. It is Eclipse/OSGI telling you that an optional bundle 'org.eclipse.fx.core' could not be loaded because it requires Java 8. This bundle is used by the newer STS Dashboard implementation, but you will get the old the dashboard as a fallback option anyway so you aren't loosing any crucial functionality.

If you want to make the error go away you should run STS using a JDK 8.

How you do that precisely may depend on your OS, but typically (on Windows / Linux) you find the STS.ini file and add the following two lines to the start of the file:

```
-vm
/home/kdvolder/java-distros/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java
```

Make sure to replace the second line with where you have the JDK 8 'java' or 'javaw.exe' executable installed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But I am not able to continue further. Getting pop up saying something like "IOException:Server returened HTTp response code: 400 for URL: http://start.spring.io"

Comment: That's a different kind of error. "start.spring.io" is a web-service used by the "New Spring Starter" project wizard to generate a boot starter project. It sounds like your STS is having trouble connecting to that service for some reason. It could be transient problem with the service or something with your internet environment. I did just try the wizard myself and it seems to be working for me right now. If problem persists, could be firewall issue or something like that.